# mongoose findByIdAndUpdate not adding item in array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to update a Role document, adding a userId into an array _users

```
/**
 * Role Schema
 */
const RoleSchema = new Schema({
  _group: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Group'},
  _users: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, trim: true, },
});
```

running the following

```
  console.log('GOING TO ADD user._id: ', user._id, 'INTO ROLE: ', req.body.roleId);
  Role.findByIdAndUpdate(new ObjectId(req.body.roleId), 
 { $addToSet: { _users: user._id }, upsert: true })
    .exec()
    .then((updatedRole) => {
      console.log('updated role: %j', updatedRole);
      res.json(updatedRole);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('ERROR SAVING ROLE: %j', e);
      throw(e);
    });
```

The _users array is NOT updated ... why ?

```
    GOING TO ADD user._id:  59577f9b660489066515ce9c INTO ROLE:  59577f99660489066515ce95

    Mongoose: roles.findAndModify({ _id: ObjectId("59577f99660489066515ce95") }, [], { '$addToSet': 
 { _users: ObjectId("59577f9b660489066515ce9c") } }, 
 { new: false, upsert: false, fields: {} })

    updated role: {"_id":"59577f99660489066515ce95","__v":0,
 "_group":"59577f99660489066515ce92","name":"admin",
 "description":"can RW group, user","rolePermissions":[],
 "permissions":[{"resourceName":"group",
  "authorizedActions":["read","write"]}
  {"resourceName":"user","authorizedActions":["read","write"]}],
  "_users":[]}
```

Comment: Specify as an array: ```{ $addToSet: { _users: [user._id] }```

Comment: thanks .. but  it doesn't change the result :  "_users":[].  still empty

Comment: yes , also tried it... no way 

roles.findAndModify({ _id: ObjectId("59578d0b01d26507af3fca6c") }, [], { '$addToSet': { _users: ObjectId("59578d0c01d26507af3fca73") } }, { new: false, upsert: false, fields: {} })

resulting in _users: []

Comment: Woow .. looked into the test DB... and it seems the role document is correctly updated... it's rather an issue w the promise return ... updatedRole...

Comment: GOT IT. need the option new: true 

In Mongoose 4.0, the default value for the new option of findByIdAndUpdate (and findOneAndUpdate) has changed to false (see #2262 of the release notes). This means that you need to explicitly set the option to true to get the new version of the doc, after the update is applied:

Comment: the document was actually getting updated but not returning the new value in the result as you have found out.

Answer (score 0):

BAD WRITING ...

In Mongoose 4.0, the default value for the new option of findByIdAndUpdate (and findOneAndUpdate) has changed to false (see #2262 of the release notes). This means that you need to explicitly set the option to true to get the new version of the doc, after the update is applied:

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateObj, {new: true}, function(err, model) {...
```

so I should rather write :

```
Role.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.roleId, { $addToSet: { _users: new ObjectId(user._id) }} , { new: true })
```